# Java, DateTimeFormatter is not considering ZoneDateTime's timezone

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I have this line of code:

```
// I pass milliseconds timestamp on time var
ZonedDateTime zonedDatetIme = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli(time), java.time.ZoneId.of("Asia/Almaty"))
```

When I try to output this time, it returns this:

```
System.our.println(zonedDatetIme)
// returns
2020-01-24T17:00+06:00[Asia/Almaty]
```

Then I'm trying to format this datetime:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm');
System.our.println(formatter.format(zonedDateTime));
```

Which returns to me this:

```
24.01.2020 05:00
```

That is wrong. It is like it substracting 6 hours of my timezone instead of adding it. Why this is happening?

Comment: 17-5=12 How did you get "It is like it substracting 6 hours of my timezone instead of adding it"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably confusing `h` and `H` - `h` is the clock hour in the sense of AM/PM (in your example: 05:00 PM = 17:00) whilst `H` is the hour of the day.